# relative url path

Tags: 7

In my anchor tag I have hard coded like this `<a href="/escorts'.my_link'"`, I want to get the relative url path. Whenever if the path is some like this in the url `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask` and I clicked on the above mentioned link then instead of `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/my_link` it gives me `escorts/my_link`. I know I did not convey my question properly. Hope anybody get my scenerio. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't fully understand your question. But I imagine two cases:

1. If you need a url that works in any page on your website, no matter where you are, you 
   need to use this code:

   ```
   <?php  
           global $base_url;
   ?>
          <a target="_blank" href="<?php print $base_url;?>/escorts'.my_link'"
   ```
2. On the other hand if you want to attach the url to the current address, use this code

   ```
   <?php  

           $path = current_path();
   ?>
          <a href="<?php print $path ;?>/escorts'.my_link'"
   ```

Comment: Thanku @Drupalist, I got the required url by using first method. But not locally it works but when I deploy it to other machine it is not clickable on the same window, I have to right click that item and open it in a new tab or window.As I am accessing using `<a href="<?php print $base_url;?>'.my_link'" windows.location="<?php print $base_url;?>'.my_link'">`

Comment: I updated the answer and it opens the link another tab. just add `target="_blank"` to `<a>`

Comment: Sorry @Drupalist, I did a mistake above. Locally it is working and links are opening in same window and in a new tab as well, this is right. But when I deployed it to other machine they are not clickable on the same window. I always have to open it in a new link or tab. I want to make working in a same window as well.

Comment: @nomeer it is about html `<a>` tag,By specifying `target` you can determine how to open the new page. for more information visit http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [l function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) it will take care of everything for you, in your example use:

```
print l('Text', 'escorts/' . my_link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

It will be like this

```
print l('Anchor text', 'my_link');
```